# When select image from memory card is nott uploading to server in android by using Multi part?

Tags: android, image, multipart, uploading, android-external-storage

In my application, when select image from external card and then upload to the server using multipart it is giving the error message as "FileNotFoundException" but the path is coming. But When i select same file from the gallery it is uploading to server.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
        final boolean isKitKatOrAbove = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKatOrAbove && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

//                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
//                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

upload image to server

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "*****";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";

        String result = "";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        //String[] q = filepath.split("/");
        //int idx = q.length - 1;

        try {
            //File file = new File(filepath);

            URL url = new URL(urlTo);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            if (file != null) {
                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + filefield + "\"; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/jpeg" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            }

            // Upload POST Data
            String[] posts = post.split("&");
            int max = posts.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                String[] kv = posts[i].split("=");

                Log.d("keys", "<>" + posts[i]);

                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + kv[0] + "\"" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(kv[1]);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            result = this.convertStreamToString(inputStream);

            if (file != null) {
                fileInputStream.close();
            }

            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MultipartRequest", "Multipart Form Upload Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
            try{
                json.put("result", "error");

            }catch(Exception e11){
                e11.printStackTrace();
            }

            return json.toString();
```

Comment: Please post your code :) without code cant help

Comment: i just post the code see once

Comment: post your send server code

Comment: @SandeepBhandari did u see the code?